# "Don't have no time" vs "don't have time"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "don't have no time" and "don't have time"? Both these expressions mean leak of time, right?

Comment: Both mean "have no time", double negative maybe has more *emphasis*?

Comment: It's double negative. See also [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113541/origin-and-correctness-of-ain-t-no), [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8777/is-there-a-rule-about-double-negations-that-arent-meant-as-double-negations-e) and the linked questions.

Answer (score 4):

Both of your expression might mean "there is no time". However,

> don't have no time

The problem with this sentence is there is  double negative, which is usually frowned upon. Literally it means you "have time" since you don't have "**no** time" which would mean you have "**some** time".  But it can mean not having any time in certain regional dialects in the US.

> don't have *any* time *(this is the idiomatic expression)*

Comment: "*We don’t need no education [...] Teacher, leave them kids alone*". It seems it's [not limited to US dialects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BP86A6vN-E).